What difference is there between Genus and 'Number of holes in a topology'?
I haven't been studying topology from a rigorous mathematical book but from more of a physics perspective so I apologise for any offence but is there any real difference between actual mathematical description of genus and just considering genus and 'Number of holes in a topology'?

My suggestion is to forget "the number of holes" and learn about homology, cohomology, etc, instead. Search this site for the keywords "holes" and "topology": whatever your actual question is, it was most likely asked in the past.

“Number of holes” is an intuitive concept that becomes unclear for more complicated examples. (An everyday example: how many holes does a T-shirt have? Is it a disc with three holes or a sphere with four holes?) “Genus” is the mathematical way of turing the concept into something rigorous (and also generalizable).
